# how to mock the backend for angularjs app?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I would like to test a factory method that runs $resource. My test would mock the real backend that does not exist yet.

Here is a sample factory code:

```
app.factory( 'Global', function( $resource ){
  var Jogas = $resource('/jogasok/:id', {'id': '@id'}, {
    'ujBerlet': {'method': 'POST', 'params': {'berlet': true}}
  });
  var jogasok = Jogas.query();
  return {
    getJogasok: function() {
      return jogasok;
    }
  };
})
```

My test would be to check that query was made.

If I initialize my app with:

```
app.run( function run ($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/jogasok').respond([
        {id: 1, name: 'asdfasdf'}, 
        {id: 2, name: '2wrerwert'}
      ]);
})
```

and open the app in my browser, then everything seems to be fine, I have the dummy data in the browser.

But, when I take out the run code above, and write a test, things just don't work.

```
describe( 'Global Service: ', function() {

  beforeEach( module('bkJoga') );
  beforeEach( inject(function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/jogasok').respond([
      {id: 1, name: 'asdfasdf'}, 
      {id: 2, name: '2wrerwert'}
    ]);
  }));

  it('getJogasok should return everyone', inject(function(Global) {
    expect(JSON.stringify(Global.getJogasok())).toBe(JSON.stringify([
      {id: 1, name: 'asdfasdf'}, 
      {id: 2, name: '2wrerwert'}
    ]));
  }));
});
```

fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working test for the factory as you posted it. I added a variable $httpBackend for the injected httpBackend. And a call to $httpBackend.flush(). <kbd>[**fiddle-demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/zVUL2/)</kbd> (read to the end for full description of fiddle content)

```
describe( 'Global Service: ', function() {
    var Global, $httpBackend

    // load the relevant application module, with the service to be tested
    beforeEach( module('bkJoga') );

    beforeEach( function() {

        // inject the mock for the http backend
        inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
        // mock the response to a particular get request
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/jogasok').respond([
            {id: 1, name: 'asdfasdf'}, 
            {id: 2, name: '2wrerwert'}
        ]);
        // inject the service to be tested
        inject(function(_Global_) {
            Global = _Global_;
        });
    });

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(!!Global).toBe(true);
    });

    it('getJogasok should return everyone', function() {
        $httpBackend.flush();    // <------------ need to flush $httpBackend
        expect(JSON.stringify(Global.getJogasok())).toBe(JSON.stringify([
            {id: 1, name: 'asdfasdf'}, 
            {id: 2, name: '2wrerwert'}
        ]));
    });
});
```

In any event, I would rewrite the factory a bit differently, because, as it is currently written, it queries the database only upon instantiation `var jogasok = Jogas.query();`. Because [services in angularjs are singletons](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services), in your app you will have only the data as they are at the time of instantiation. Therefore, later modifications to the data will not be reflected in your factory. 
Here is an example of the factory and its unit-test that reflects this idea.

the factory:

```
app.factory('GlobalBest', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/jogasok/:id', {
        'id': '@id'
    }, {
        'ujBerlet': {
            'method': 'POST',
                'params': {
                'berlet': true
            }
       }
    });
});
```

the test:

```
describe('GlobalBest Service: ', function () {
    var srv, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module('bkJoga'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        // inject the mock for the http backend
        inject(function (_$httpBackend_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });

        // inject the service to be tested
        inject(function (_GlobalBest_) {
            srv = _GlobalBest_;
        });
    });

    it('should exist', function () {
        expect( !! srv).toBe(true);
    });

    it('query() should return everyone', function () {

        // mock the response to a particular get request
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/jogasok').respond([{
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdfasdf'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: '2wrerwert'
        }]);

        // send request to get everyone
        var data = srv.query();

        // flush the pending request
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(JSON.stringify(data)).toBe(JSON.stringify([{
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdfasdf'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: '2wrerwert'
        }]));
    });

    it('get({id: 1}) should return object with id=1', function () {
        // mock the response to a particular get request
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/jogasok/1').respond({
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdfasdf'
        });
        var datum = srv.get({
            id: 1
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(JSON.stringify(datum)).toBe(JSON.stringify({
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdfasdf'
        }));
    });
});
```

I wrote a <kbd>[**fiddle-demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/zVUL2/)</kbd> with 3 versions of the service: your original service 'Global', a new version 'GlobalNew' that returns the query() method, and finally a version 'GlobalBest' that returns directly the $resource. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried it, but it fails with an error: Error: No pending request to flush !

The factory code is as you can see it in my question. Thus Jogas.query is supposed to run when Global is injected. Still, adding a success/error callbacks to it, shows it's never called.

Comment: I took the factory code from your question and can run the above test successfully. Try to test if the service has been instantiated in the test: `it('should exist', function(){ expect(!!Global).toBe(true); });`

Comment: Also, because your Global service executes a query() when instantiated, you may need to move $httpBackend.whenGet() before ingecting the 'Global' service. I noticed that is the case if running the test in jsfiddle. I modified the code above to reflect this change.

Answer (score 2):

try changing it from `.toBe` to `.toEqual`. Jasmine does object reference equality with `toBe`, and deep comparison with `toEqual`.

Comment: thx for the remark, but the real question here is about mocking the http request

Answer (score 1):

Until now the best answer I could get was to create another app, that inherits my app + uses the ngMockE2E service. This way it should be possible to mock out these requests.

note: unfortunately, I could not get it working yet with my testing environment

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.mock.inject` to create the mocked the instance of the service and then you need call `flush()` of the mock `$httpBackend`, which allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests and thus preserving the async api of the backend, while allowing the test to execute synchronously.

```
describe('Global Service: ', function () {
    var srv;

    beforeEach(module('bkJoga'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            srv = $injector.get('Global');
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.flush();
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/jogasok').respond([{
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdfasdf'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: '2wrerwert'
        }]);
    }));

    it('getJogasok should return everyone', inject(function (Global) {
        expect(JSON.stringify(Global.getJogasok())).toBe(JSON.stringify([{
            id: 1,
            name: 'asdfasdf'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: '2wrerwert'
        }]));
    }));
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zsong/6AW6t/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A nice article on AngularJS testing that touches on backend mocks too: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/