# Why unit testing response is always successful?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I was reading posts related for don't repeat the question.

I have the next unit testing code:

```
describe('service', function() {
var questionApiService;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_questionApiService_) {
    questionApiService = _questionApiService_;
}));

// Test service availability
it('check the existence of get field question service', inject(function(questionApiService) {
//expect(1).toEqual(100);

    questionApiService.getField()
        .then(function(data) {

            //console.log(data);
            expect(1).toEqual(100);
        });
}));
```

});

If I run the code `expect(1).toEqual(100);` outside the service, the result is Error, but if I write the same code `expect(1).toEqual(100);` inside the service, the result is Success, which makes me think that the validator is not entering the service.

Whats wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

Hello Asta, I think ur idea is very good and i'm trying to implement it. I have an error in my code and i don't know how do debugging:

```
defer = $q.defer();
spyOn(questionApiService, 'getField').andReturn(defer.promise);
defer.resolve(data);
expect(data.nextQ).toEqual(1);
```

My unit testing always fails. If promise is successful, the "data" object must have nextQ attribute.

**EDIT 2:**

Hi Asta, your code is amazing. I'm trying to execute your code in my system and still with error. The ut fails:

Error: Unexpected request: GET http://mi.url.com/api/thefield   No more request expected

Do u know what's wrong? Clarify that the code works fine on my application but ut is the problem.

Question Api Service code:

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
    .factory('questionApiService', function($http, $q) {
        var myService = {
            getField: function() {
                var defer = $q.defer();

                $http.get('http://mi.url.com/api/thefield')
                .success( function(data) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                })
                .error( function(data) {
                    defer.reject(data);
                });

                return defer.promise;
            };

        return myService;
    });
```

Your test:

```
describe('myApp', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
    });

    describe('questionApiService', function () {
        it('should check the existence of get field question service', inject(function($rootScope, questionApiService) {
            var response = null;
            var promise = questionApiService.getField();

            promise.then(function(data) {
                response = data;
            });

            $rootScope.$apply();

            var expectedResponse = { "nextQ": 1 };
            console.log(response);
            //expect(JSON.parse(response.nextQ)).toEqual(expectedResponse.nextQ);
        }));

    });
});
```

Comment: Providing the code of `getField` function would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Yazaki, the getField function is a service that returns a json object. In my app works fine, but i don't know what happens in the ut. Thank u.

Comment: For debugging you can check the output form a failing `expect`. If `expect(data).toEqual(1);` fails then the Jasmine output should tell you why it failed i.e. expected `something` to equal `something`. If your data has the nextQ property then that should be in the output

Comment: Actually, I had a think about this and you want to test this service rather than mock it out with a spy. I've created a jsFiddle to test an example service. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move your expectation outside the `then` and do a `$rootScope.$apply()`.

```
it('should check the existence of the get field question service', inject(function($rootScope, questionApiService) {
    response = null;
    promise = questionApiService.getField()
    promise.then(function(data) {
        response = data;
        });
     $rootScope.$apply();

    expectedResponse = { "nextQ": "value" }
    expect(JSON.parse(response)).toEqual(expectedResponse);
}));
```

I created a jsFiddle you can use to play around with. It sets up a service that returns JSON via a promise which I used to test http://jsfiddle.net/neridum/9uumwfzc/

Alternatively if you want to test this service from another service you can mock it out using spies. Here you would mock the response as a promise and then resolve it

```
defer = $q.defer();
spyOn(questionApiService, 'getField').andReturn(defer.promise);
defer.resolve(data);
expect(data).toEqual('100');
```

Comment: Hello Asta, thank u for ur answer. Apologies for the delay of my comment. Kindly check my edit 1.

Comment: Updated my answer for testing this service directly which is what I think you were actually asking

Comment: You should just need to mock out the http request using something like         $httpBackend.whenGET('mi.url.com/api/thefield').respond([{...}]);. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412192/how-to-mock-the-backend-for-angularjs-app